# Workbook_Open Subscript out of Range

Tags: vba, excel

I am having issues with writing a macro in VBA when it is being initiated with the opening of my workbook. The error reads 'Error 9 - Subscript out of range'.

The Macro should look to see if there is a 'control' sheet in the current workbook, if not then it will open another workbook and copy the control sheet over - closing that workbook as it does so.

This is a strange one because it actually works if I attach it to a button, but doesn't work when I try and initiate the Macro when you open the file.

Here is my code;

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    ' CreateEUC Macro

    ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    If Worksheets(i).Name = "Control" Then
    exists = True
    MsgBox ("There is already an EUC slide in this workbook")
    End If
    Next i
    If Not exists Then

    ' Open Location
        Workbooks.Open "T:\Pricing\EUC Inventory\EUC Control Sheet v0.4.xlsx"

    ' Copy/Paste EUC
        Sheets("Control").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    ' Close EUC Workbook
        Workbooks("EUC Control Sheet v0.4.xlsx").Close savechanges:=False

    ' Move sheet at front of workbook
        Sheets("Control").Move Before:=Sheets(1)
        Range("A1:H1").Select

    End If

    ScreenUpdating = True


    End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: The error is happening in the 'Copy/Paste EUC' line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you haven't qualified which workbook contains worksheet "Control", you're implicitly referring to the activeworkbook, and you've already proven that worksheet "Control" doesn't exist... Qualify your worksheet reference (oh, and always declare your variables!)

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim exists As Boolean
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        If Worksheets(i).Name = "Control" Then
            exists = True
            MsgBox ("There is already an EUC slide in this workbook")
        End If
    Next i
    If Not exists Then
        With Workbooks.Open("T:\Pricing\EUC Inventory\EUC Control Sheet v0.4.xlsx") ' Open Location
            .Sheets("Control").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) ' Copy/Paste EUC
            .Close savechanges:=False ' Close EUC Workbook
        End With
        Sheets("Control").Move Before:=Sheets(1) ' Move sheet to front of workbook
        Range("A1:H1").Select
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```